# How to store ClientID and ClientSecret in a K8 Env

Tags: sso, configuration, secret-sharing, secrets-management, kubernetes

I am trying integrate our service with SSO. I have generated the ClientID and ClientSecret.

Is it a good security practice to store the ClientID and ClientSecret as a configmap? If not, what are the alternatives for storing and using them?

**ConfigMap Example**

```
application.yml: |
    spring:
      security:
        oauth2:
          client:
            registration:
              testService:
                client-id: test
                client-secret: <Can i hardcode Secret Here>
                authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
```

Answer (score 1):

For storing secrets values in Kubernetes, it's generally recommended to either use the in-built `secret` object type, or to use a third party secret store.

[Kubernetes secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) may be suitable for some use cases, if you want something with more options around security [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) from Hashicorp is an often used option.

Also, if you're using a cloud managed version of Kubernetes (e.g. AKS, EKS, GKE) you could use your cloud providers secret store.